# how to pass two inputs in one reactive function to distinguish data on the basis of both

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server, shinydashboard

```
biz1 = data.frame(

  Stock = query11$MONTHNAME,

  SaleDate=query11$SALE_DATE,
  Total = as.numeric(as.character(query11$TOTAL)),

  NumberOfBills=query11$TRIID,
  year=query11$YEAR,
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE

)      
output$Box3 = renderUI(
        if (USER$Logged==TRUE){
          selectInput("yr","select a year",c(unique(biz1$year),"pick one"),"pick one")
        })

      output$Box4= renderUI(

        if (USER$Logged==TRUE)
        {
          if (is.null(input$yr) || input$yr == "pick one"){return()
          }else selectInput("sector", 
                            "Select a Month", 
                            c(unique(biz1$Stock[which(biz1$year%in%input$yr)]),"pick one"),
                            "pick one")



        })
```

here is the subdata2 is the reactive function where i want to distinguish data on the basis of both input but i am not to pass in correct format

```
  subdata2 = reactive(biz1[which(biz1$Stock%in%input$sector),]&&biz1[which(biz1$Stock%in%input$yr)])
```

Comment: any help how to do this

Comment: what do you mean be distinguish the data? Please provide a reproducible example.

Comment: means is that if i am select october as a month it is showing a data of october of year 2016 and 2017 but i want only 2017 data

Answer (score 0):

Since there was not enough information and no reproducible example, I have tried to solve the question assuming that there was no error generated in Shiny and that the problem was subsetting the data.

**Your code to subset the data**

```
subdata2 = reactive(biz1[which(biz1$Stock%in%input$sector),]&&biz1[which(biz1$Stock%in%input$yr)])
```

There are 3 mistakes that I see:

1. `which(biz1$Stock%in%input$yr)`, here you are subsetting the `Stock` column using the `input$yr` value
2. The use of `&&` vs `&`, here the longer form evaluates left to right examining only the first element of each vector. Check `?"&&"`to learn more
3. The use of `which`, in your code you are subsetting the same data frame separately and then comparing them with `&&`, instead you should, for eg. `biz1[which(biz1$Stock %in% input$sector & biz1$year %in% input$yr),]`

**Full Solution**

```
library(shiny)

biz1 = data.frame(Stock = 1:12, year = 2016:2017, test = c("a", "b", "c"),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("Box3"),
  uiOutput("Box4"),
  dataTableOutput("tbl")
)


server <-  function(input, output, session){

  output$Box3 = renderUI({
    selectInput("yr","select a year",c(unique(biz1$year),"pick one"),"pick one")
  })

  output$Box4= renderUI({

    if (is.null(input$yr) || input$yr == "pick one") { 
      return()
    } else selectInput("sector", 
                       "Select a Month", 
                       c(unique(biz1$Stock[which(biz1$year%in%input$yr)]),"pick one"),
                       "pick one")
  })

  # Note the usage of 'which' and '&' to subset the data frame
  output$tbl <- renderDataTable({
    biz1[which((biz1$Stock%in%input$sector) & (biz1$year%in%as.numeric(input$yr))), ]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: its not working showing error :-invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'

Comment: I don't know what did you try. can you be more elaborate? In the solution above, I've not used `&&`, so I can't say where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

You can use filter fn

```
subdata2 = reactive({
  x <- filter(biz1,Stock%in%input$sector, year%in%input$yr)
  x
})
```